# i want to get data from sql data in ajax but not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am working withphp ajax but it not responding, but once i remove a row it works help.

this is my code search_query.php

```
if (isset($_POST['user_post'])) {
   $post_user = array();
   $user_post = $con->prepare("SELECT * from post where poster_id= ?");
   $user_post->execute([$id]);
   while($row = $user_post->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $post_user[] = '<div id="thread" class="card promoting-card thread mt-2">
       <div class="card-body d-flex flex-row">
           <img src="http://localhost/lasu/img/user-profile.png" class="rounded-circle mr-3" height="50px" width="50px" alt="avatar">
           <div>
               <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold mb-2" style="text-align:left;"> '.strtoupper(user_detail($row['poster_id'], "username")).'</h4>
               <p class="card-text"><i class="far fa-clock pr-2"></i>'. time_elapsed_string($row['reg_date'], $full = false).' </p>
                <p>'.$row['post_content'].'</p>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>';
    }
   echo json_encode($post_user);
   }
```

and this is javascript

```
 $(function(){
    var search_data = new FormData();
    search_data.append("user_post", 'post');
    search_data.append("user_post_id", <?php echo get_users_page_id(); ?>);
    $.ajax({  
              url:"search_query.php",  
              type: 'POST', 
              data:search_data,  
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              dataType: 'json',  
              success:function(data)
              {
                if (data.length < 1) {
                    $('#results').append('<font>No Post</font><br>');
                }else{
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $('#results').append(data[i]+'<br>');
                    }
                }
              } 
          })
        })
```

It works if i remove **$row['post_content']** in the php code and i tried it in a plain page it worked pls help

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you forgot to get the id?

```
if (isset($_POST['user_post'])) {
   $post_user = array();
   $user_post = $con->prepare("SELECT * from post where poster_id= ?");
   // here
   $id = $_POST['user_post_id'];
   $user_post->execute([$id]);
   while($row = $user_post->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $contents = highlight_contents($row['post_content']);
       $post_user[] = '<div id="thread" class="card promoting-card thread mt-2">
       <div class="card-body d-flex flex-row">
           <img src="http://localhost/lasu/img/user-profile.png" class="rounded-circle mr-3" height="50px" width="50px" alt="avatar">
           <div>
               <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold mb-2" style="text-align:left;"> '.strtoupper(user_detail($row['poster_id'], "username")).'</h4>
               <p class="card-text"><i class="far fa-clock pr-2"></i>'. time_elapsed_string($row['reg_date'], $full = false).' </p>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>';
    }
   echo json_encode($post_user);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @11 but i did not forget id

Comment: What did you change and why?